# Placement new on memory returned by new and new[]

Tags: c++, placement-new

Below is my test class:-

```
class Base
{
public:
    int data;
    Base(int x) : data(x) {}
};
```

Now, I am using placement new to create objects on already allocated memory:-

CASE_1:-

```
void* raw = operator new(4* sizeof(Base));
Base* b = static_cast<Base*>(raw);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    new (&b[i]) Base(i);
```

CASE_2:-

```
void* raw = operator new[](4* sizeof(Base));  <<<<<<<<<<<<<
Base* b = static_cast<Base*>(raw);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    new (&b[i]) Base(i);
```

In CASE_1 I used plain `new` to allocate enough memory whereas in Case_2 I used `new[]` to do that allocation. Both are working fine as I tested:-

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Base* b1 = b;
    cout << (*(b1+i)).data;
}
```

However, I am confused whether CASE_1 is the right way of doing the memory allocation for array of objects. Are both of these approaches similar.

Comment: The right way to allocate arrays in c++ is to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: @Mgetz: Usually, yes. But sometimes you want to avoid the cost of initialising the allocated memory, and there's no (well-defined) way to do that with `vector`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour [I do believe there is actually](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)

Comment: If you just want to allocate a chunk of memory of a specific size, why use the confusing `operator new` function, instead of using the operator `new[]` using e.g. `int8_t`? The result will be the same, but less confusing to read.

Comment: Also, if you have special allocation needs, you should probably use `std::vector` with a custom allocator.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Nice idea. But isn't use of new[4] would construct objects along with allocating memory.

Comment: @ravi Not if you allocate e.g. `int8_t`, like `int8_t* raw = new int8_t[4 * sizeof(Base)];`, that just allocates a chunk of bytes, without any initialization or construction.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/):

> The default definition allocates memory by calling operator new: ::operator new (size).

Judging from this, the result should be exactly the same. Both lines should return an identical pointer.

As @Joachim Pileborg pointed out, you should probably avoid `operator new`and use the simpler `new Base[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty in answering this question is that there must be some "really weird thing" in play before using placement new is a good idea. Without knowing what that thing is, it's difficult to say with any confidence that what you're doing is "right".

They do both work.

Using global `operator new[]` is fairly pointless. All it gives you over global `operator new` is the ability for you (or some other code in your program) to overload them to do different things, for example to allocate from different sources. So you might consider it slightly better practice to use `operator new[]` for allocations that are probably large, and then you could later optimize for that purpose elsewhere in your program. But that's a fairly blunt instrument compared with directly using specific allocators for specific purposes. I really don't think it's common, but then using global new *at all* isn't common.

Also, you don't show the code to release the memory so there's plenty of opportunity there to get it wrong. In general you must call the destructors of each element in turn, then call the global delete operator that matches the new operator you used. For your particular class `Base` there's actually no harm in failing to destruct it, but if you leave out the destructor calls and later change `Base` you could run into trouble.